# ASP.NET MVC 4 binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, data-binding, razor-2

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET MVC and i began a small project. I created CRUD methods in my controller and it works. I just have a problem with a method i created to see the details of a form (my project is to create forms with a backoffice). I'll show you the code:

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Detail(Guid id)
    {
        Form formDetail = null;

        using (var ctx = new FormsContext())
        {
            formDetail = ctx.Forms.Find(id);
        }

        return View(formDetail);
    }
```

The model:

```
public class Form
{
    public Guid FormId { get; set; }
    public string Titre { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DateCloture { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListeQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

And the view:

```
@model ProjetESGIForm.Models.Form

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Detail";
}

<h2>Detail</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Titre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateCloture)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I debug the project all the views work except the detail one ... I have the titre description and datecloture but no datas ...

If you have any idea, you're welcome !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change View to :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Titre)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Titre)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateCloture)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateCloture)
    </td>
</tr>
```